# ajax-datatables-rails undefined method search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables-1.10

I am trying to implement rails server side datatable with ajax-datatables-rails gem. When I want to see table, I get an error undefined method search. This is my code

```
 class ContractorDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base

  def view_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    # or in aliased_join_table.column_name format
    @view_columns ||= {
       id: { source: "Contractor.id", cond: :eq },
       name: { source: "Contractor.name" },
       city: { source: "Contractor.city" },
       ico: { source: "Contractor.ico" },
       country: { source: "Contractor.country" }
    }
  end
  def data
    records.map do |contractor|
      {
        # example:
         id: contractor.id,
         name: contractor.name,
         city: contractor.city,
         ico: contractor.ico,
         country: contractor.country
        }
    end
  end
  private
def contractors
  @contractors ||= fetch_records
end
def get_raw_records
  Contractor.all
end
def get_raw_record_count
  search_records(get_raw_records).count
end

end
```

In my controller I put it into index

```
class ContractorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:showcontractor,:listcontractors,:index]
  before_action :set_contractor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html, :json
  # GET /contractors
  # GET /contractors.json
  def index
    @contractors = Contractor.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        render json: ::ContractorDatatable.new(view_context)
      end
    end
  end
```

and javascript is simple calling this json from ajax. But in console I see that get request for JSON returns 0 records and undefined method search error.

> NoMethodError (undefined method `search' for
>   "Contractor.name":String):

I have experience with datatables and server side in PHP, but I am kinda lost how it works in rails.
thx

edit:
javascript code

```
var tableconready = function() {
    $('#admindodavatelia').DataTable({
      'order': [0, 'asc'],
      'serverSide': true,
      'ajax' : '/contractors.json',
      'language': {
       'url': '/datatables_slovak.json'
      }
    });
    };
  $(".contractors.index").ready(tableconready);
  $(".contractors.index").on('turbolinks:load', tableconready);
```

edit2:
I cleaned the ContractorDatatable code to have it like in tutorial, but I get

> (1.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contractors"    (2.0ms)  SELECT
>   COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT "contractors".* FROM "contractors") AS foo
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
>
>   app/datatables/contractor_datatable.rb:20:in`data'
>   app/controllers/contractors_controller.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in
>   index'   app/controllers/contractors_controller.rb:10:in`index'

Comment: and your javascript code? Who do you request the datatable?

Comment: added javascript code..what do you mean by who do you request?

Comment: Who generate the url you request the datatable

Comment: what tutorial you follow? (I do not understand some lines in your AjaxDatatable file, like model_name = .. columns = , searchable_columns = , super...)

Comment: which branch are you using of ajax-datatables-rails?

Comment: actually I tried several tutorials this one was first http://ajahongir.github.io/ajax-datatables-rails/ but instead of coffee I call standard javascript
when I cleaned the code from that initialize part to have it like in the tutorial, I get nil for records

Comment: branch is v-0-4-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
var tableconready = function() {
    $('#admindodavatelia').DataTable({
      'order': [0, 'asc'],
      'serverSide': true,
      'ajax' : '/contractors.json',
      'language': {
       'url': '/datatables_slovak.json'
      },
      columns: [
        {data: 'id' },
        {data: 'name' },
        {data: 'city' },
        {data: 'ico' },
        {data: 'country' },
      ]

    });
  };
  $(".contractors.index").ready(tableconready);
  $(".contractors.index").on('turbolinks:load', tableconready);
```

You miss the definition of columns

And in the AjaxDatatable the `get_raw_record_count` and `contractors` functions you do not need it.

Answer (score 1):

I just check that this is a gem version issue of `ajax-datatables-rails`. I got the same issue when I am using version 0.4.0 but when switching back to 0.3.1 this issue goes out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are 2 types of binding datatable.net and datatable.rb columns:

1. by default datatable.net pass columns by index.

   ```
   class CityDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base

     def view_columns

       @view_columns ||= {
         '0' => { source: "City.id", cond: :eq },
         '1' => { source: "City.name" },
         ...
       }

     end
   end


   $('#city').DataTable({
     'serverSide': true,
     'ajax' : '/cities.json'
   });
   ```
2. binding by column name.

   ```
   class CityDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base

     def view_columns
       @view_columns ||= {
         **id**: { source: "City.id", cond: :eq },
         **name**: { source: "City.name" },
         ...
       }
     end
   end


   $('#city').DataTable({
     'serverSide': true,
     'ajax' : '/contractors.json'
   },
   columns: [
     {data: '**id**' },
     {data: '**name**' },
     ...
   ]
   });
   ```